# What should a mechanic charge for a breather valve replacement?

Tags: vw, cel, jetta

I just got an estimate for a CEL on my 2007 Jetta. The diagnosis was:

> valve cover with seal. Breather valve in valve cove has failed.

Is this a serious issue that I should get fixed now?

They are telling me the price of the fix is $567.00. Is this is a fair price?

EDIT: The engine is a 2.5 L 5-cylinder

Comment: Sounds like the breather valve must be integrated into the valve cover.  On older cars, I've see that valve be a separate piece.  You need to clarify that with them, because that sounds way high if there's a way to replace just the valve.

Comment: What engine does your Jetta have?

Comment: did they give you a breakdown of the quote? it's probably integrated into the valve cover.

Comment: $100 - $200 for a replacement valve cover, leaves ~ $350 - $450 dollars of labor for a job that a reasonable person could do themselves in 30 minutes, you decide if that is fair.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It is 2.5 L 5-cylinder

Comment: Get another diagnosis & quote...

Comment: they are clearly replacing the whole cover which could easily be  $3-400 for a genuine factory part.  You can search yourself for the part price, but it is getting off topic to ask recommendations on where to shop.

Comment: Keep in mind that changing a valve cover on a modern car is not a simple task in many cases. There is a lot of "stuff" in the way, plus you've got to put it all back and make sure it works properly when you're done. That said, I'd still get another quote and/or look into just replacing the broken part as outlined below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked around a little, and it looks like you have 2 options.  The shop is probably quoting you the cost of replacing the entire valve cover which does have a built in vent:

[image]

[Valve cover on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ACN3EBW)

This cover is $100 on Amazon, but they are probably quoting OEM prices + labor, so that might technically be a "valid quote", but it still seems very high.  Get another quote before you do anything, or...

Notice the circle on the front of that valve cover.  That is normally the part that goes bad because it has a rubber seal that fails.  A third party company has started to make just that part:

[image]

[Dorman replacement PCV diaphram](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CFJT6AE)

So, for $20, you might be able to fix this yourself.  I'm not sure if the trouble codes need to be manually cleared for this fix or if the CEL will go away on its own.

Even if you want or need to replace the whole valve cover, it might be something you can do yourself or with the help of a handy friend.  It's a pretty basic repair.

Note:  I'm not endorsing Amazon for auto parts - it's just easy to search and most people are familiar with it.  Shop around, or even check local parts stores.